# Formatting tikzpicture plots side by side/ how to use \begin{figure}[htdp] or \begin{figure}[h]

Tags: comments

I'm new latex. I've been trying to learn how to format these plots side by side on one line, but I have not been able to successfully. I don't understand how to use the \begin{figure}[h] feature or the subfigure. Any help would be appreciated.

```
**\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
    \usepackage{amsmath,bm, graphicx, pgfplots}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{ {Figure_1.png}, {logo.gif} }
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{nccmath}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{hyphenat}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subfigure}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
    
    
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering 
        \subfigure[Figure A]{\label{fig:a}
             \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0pt]
            \begin{axis}[
                xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
                ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
                axis lines=center,
                axis on top=true,
                domain=-2.5:2.5,
                ylabel=$y$,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ]
            \\
                \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {0.5*(1 +tanh(\x))};
                \node [right, red] at (axis cs: -1.1,1.1) {$y = 0.5 *(1 + \tanh x)$};
                
                %% Add the asymptotes
                \draw [blue, dotted, thick] (axis cs:-2.5,0)-- (axis cs:2.5,0);
                \draw [blue, dotted, thick] (axis cs:-2.5,+1)-- (axis cs:2.5,+1);
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture} 
        }
        \subfigure[Figure B]{\label{fig:b}
          \begin{tikzpicture}[
              declare function={
                func(\x)= (\x <= 0) * (0)   +
                          and(\x > 0 , \x < 1) * (\x)     +
                          (\x >= 1) * (1)
               ;
              }
            ]
            \begin{axis}[
                xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
                ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
                axis lines=center,
                axis on top=true,
                domain=-2.5:2.5,
                ylabel=$y$,
                xlabel=$x$,
            ]
            
            \addplot [blue,thick] {func(\x)};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture} 
       }
        \subfigure[Figure B]{\label{fig:c}
         \begin{tikzpicture}[
              declare function={
                gunc(\x)= (\x <= 0) * (0)   +
                          (\x > 0) * (\x)     
               ;
              }
            ]
            \begin{axis}[
                xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
                ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
                axis lines=center,
                axis on top=true,
                domain=-2.5:2.5,
                ylabel=$y$,
                xlabel=$x$,
            ]
            
            \addplot [cyan,thick] {gunc(\x)};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture} 
        \label{fig:image3}
        }
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[
                        axis y line = middle,
                        axis x line = middle,
                        xlabel = $x$,
                        ylabel = {$f(x) = x^3$},
                        grid=major,
                    ]
                    \addplot [
                        domain=-3:3, 
                        samples=100, 
                        color=red,
                    ]
                    {x^3};
                    \addlegendentry{$x^3$}
                    %
                    \addplot [
                        domain=-3:3, 
                        samples=100, 
                        color=blue,
                        ]
                        {x^3 + 3};
                    \addlegendentry{$x^3 + 3$}
                     %
                    \addplot [
                        domain=-3:3, 
                        samples=100, 
                        color=green,
                        ]
                        {x^3 - 3};
                    \addlegendentry{$x^3 - 3$}
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{subfigure}
            %\hfill
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[
                        axis y line = middle,
                        axis x line = middle,
                        xlabel = $x$,
                        ylabel = {$f(x) = x^3$},
                        grid=major,
                    ]
                    \addplot [
                        domain=-3:3, 
                        samples=100, 
                        color=red,
                    ]
                    {x^3};
                    \addlegendentry{$x^3$}
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{subfigure}
            \caption{lajsdfls}
        \end{figure}
    \end{document}**
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the main site.

Comment: Any news? Does the answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your document example has many issues:

1. Each package load only once (for example, you load `graphicx` three times!).
2. Be aware, if any of loaded package is obsolete, for example `subfigure` is replaced by `subfig`, however the most powerful package for sub -figures and -tables is `subcaption` package.
3. For floats placement you should enable, that LaTeX can select optimal position in the document. For example, use only `h` not enable this, so it is good to add options `t` (top), or `b` (bottom) or `p` (page) or combination of all.

   Many people, that they not "boring" with floats placement, in preamble add

   ```
   \makeatletter
      \def\fps@figure{hbtp}
      \def\fps@table{hbtp}
   \makeatother
   ```

   and than don't write float placement (see MWE below).
4. Use, if possible, recent version of packages (they have new, improved features, removed discovered bugs, etc. For example, instead ancient `pgfplots` version 1.7 use recent version 1.18.
5. Make yourself familiar with used packages: read their documentations (well, some packages have huge documentation, but such usually contain tutorials for their use)

So, for your document I would use preamble with recent version of LaTeX and all packages as is in the following MWE (which base on [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604132/formatting-tikzpicture-plots-side-by-side-how-to-use-beginfigurehtdp-or-b) on one  of yours previous question:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{ {Figure_1.png}, {logo.gif} }
\usepackage{nccmath}    % it load amsmath too
\usepackage{array, multirow}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\makeatletter
   \def\fps@figure{hbtp}
   \def\fps@table{hbtp}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyphenat}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \pgfplotsset{
        xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
        ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
        axis lines=center,
        axis on top=true,
        domain=-2.5:2.5,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xlabel=$x$,
                }

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,]
    \begin{axis}
\addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {0.5*(1 +tanh(\x))};
\node [right, red] at (-1.1,1.1) {$y = 0.5 *(1 + \tanh x)$};
%% Add the asymptotes
\draw [blue, dotted, thick] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0);
\draw [blue, dotted, thick] (-2.5,1) -- (2.5,1);
    \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{one}
    \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}%
\hfill%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,
    declare function={func(\x)= (\x <=0) * (0)  +
                                and(\x >0, \x < 1) * (\x) +
                                (\x >=1) * (1);}
                            ]
    \begin{axis}
\addplot [blue,thick] {func(\x)};
    \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{two}
    \label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,
    declare function={gunc(\x)= (\x <=0) * (0) +
                                (\x > 0) * (\x);}
                            ]
    \begin{axis}
\addplot [cyan,thick] {gunc(\x)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{three}
\label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Three graphs}
\label{fig:image3}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]